# How does ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.Builder handles deletions and get?

Tags: java, data-structures, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I use [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java) as `LRUCache` and I'm curious how it handles `.get` after `deletion` of a key (because we'll eventually have to remove keys from `LRUCache` due to its policy.

```
entityLRUCache = new ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.Builder<GUID, Entity>()
                                            .maximumWeightedCapacity(100)
                                            .build();

...

Entity getEntity(GUID entityId)
{
    if (entityLRUCache.containsKey(entityId))
    {
        // Question: what if key gets deleted from other 
        // thread (when we jumped into this if statement) 
        // and then we'll try to retrieve it here using .get()
        return entityLRUCache.get(entityId);
    }
    else
    {
        Entity entity = longLoadFromDatabase(entityId);
        entityLRUCache.put(entityId, entity);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

How can I handle these type of situations with this `ConcurrentLinkedHashMap` class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you would would want to avoid reading multiple times from the cache to avoid race conditions. Instead you would write this as,

```
Entity getEntity(GUID entityId) {
  Entity entity = entityLRUCache.get(entityId);
  if (entity == null) {
    entity = longLoadFromDatabase(entityId);
    entityLRUCache.put(entityId, entity);
  }
  return entity;
}
```

This has a race, called a cache stampede, when loading the value to populate on a miss. For that library, one might write a decorator using lock striping or storing futures to avoid this if problematic. The Google Code wiki used to provide an example of how to write a [SelfPopulatingMap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap/blob/wiki/SelfPopulatingCache.md).

`ConcurrentLinkedHashMap` merged into Guava and evolved into [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine). You should prefer that library, where you could write this as,

```
Entity getEntity(GUID entityId) {
  return entityCache.get(entityId, this::longLoadFromDatabase);
}
```

Comment: Will the latter option have a cache stampede as well?

Comment: Nope, it handles that for you (lock free read, followed by per-entry lock to compute it absent).

Comment: How can I nicely tune the latter option if `longLoadFromDatabase` is async (i.e. returns `Single` from RxJava)?

Comment: I did find `write-behind-rxjava` but it's not really clear to me still.

Comment: @AlexKokorin Have you considered `AsyncLoadingCache`?