# How can I cache items in RxJava and avoid cache stampede?

Tags: java-8, rx-java2, caffeine

Let's say I've got the following code:

```
Entity getEntity(GUID entityId) {
  Entity entity = entityLRUCache.get(entityId);
  if (entity == null) {
    entity = longLoadFromDatabase(entityId);
    entityLRUCache.put(entityId, entity);
  }
  return entity;
}
```

[Thanks to @BenManes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078766/how-does-concurrentlinkedhashmap-builder-handles-deletions-and-get/50078971?noredirect=1#comment87176424_50078971) I can use Caffeine framework to solve cache stampede:

```
Entity getEntity(GUID entityId) {
  return entityCache.get(entityId, this::longLoadFromDatabase);
}
```

But now method `longLoadFromDatabase` returns a `Single<Entity>` instead of Entity itself (that 2nd argument for `get` is a mapper from `int -> Entity`), so the previous solutions won't work anymore.

Comment: Would you want to return a `Single<Entity>` from `getEntity` whis represents a completed or ongoing load from a database?

Comment: If Caffeine supports CompletionStage-based async refresh, you can use the RxJava 2 JDK 8 interop library's [`SingleInterop.get()`](https://akarnokd.github.io/RxJava2Jdk8Interop/javadoc/hu/akarnokd/rxjava2/interop/SingleInterop.html#get--) converter.

Comment: @akarnokd Yes, I'd like to return a `Single<Entity>` from `getEntity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `SingleSubject` as a placeholder in a concurrent map:

```java
ConcurrentMap<GUID, SingleSubject<Entity>> map = ...

public Single<Entity> getEntity(GUID guid) {
    SingleSubject<Entity> e = map.get(guid);
    if (e == null) {
        e = SingleSubject.create();
        SingleSubject<Entity> f = map.putIfAbsent(guid, e);
        if (f == null) {
            longLoadFromDatabase(guid).subscribe(e);
        } else {
            e = f;
        }
    }
    return e;
}
```

Comment: OK, the idea is that if I want to avoid cache stampede I should try to work with `SingleInterop.get()` anyway (the piece of code you provided doesn't handle cache stampede as far as I can see: we probably could remove the value for specified key from the other thread if we use LRUCache) ?

Comment: I'd assume your cache implementation supports the `ConcurrentMap` interface. The rest is implementation detail of the map.

Comment: @akarnokd How about using `AsyncLoadingCache` and converting between rx and `CompletableFuture`?

Comment: That was the implication of my comment on the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210449/how-can-i-cache-items-in-rxjava-and-avoid-cache-stampede/50210865?noredirect=1#comment87438229_50210449

Answer (score 1):

Combining @akarnokd suggestion with Caffeine's async support, you can use [AsyncLoadingCache](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Population#asynchronously-loading) with Rx's converters.

```
AsyncLoadingCache<Integer, Entity> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .buildAsync((key, executor) -> SingleInterop.get()
        .apply(longLoadFromDatabase(key)).toCompletableFuture());
...
return SingleInterop.fromFuture(cache.get(123));
```

The cache will automatically remove the entry if the future fails with an exception or resolves to a null value.